# Applying some css in my stylesheet form some other existing style

Tags: css

I am trying to apply css from some other existing css,
In my style sheet

I have a css

```
  .baseColor{
  color: red;
  }
```

now in my other css , i dont want to assign a hardcoded color , instead i need to use the same color whichever is in baseColor..

```
 .buttonColor{
 color: (What ever is in baseColor)
  }

 .tabColor{
   color: (What ever is in baseColor)
  }
```

is this possible

Comment: You can't do that normally but CSS Custom Properties might be an option - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*

Comment: you may use the SASS instead of using CSS.
you can assign in variable and can call from your css class.
https://www.w3schools.com/sass/showsass.php?filename=demo_sass_first